# Lua Compiling Integer differences - Windows vs Mac OSX

Tags: macos, lua, powerpc

I am a beginner to lua. I'm trying to compile some luac scripts however I notice a large difference between using luac 5.1 on Windows and Mac OSX (ppc)

When there are integer values, they are represented differently. E.g below

on Windows 10 (little endian), 62 when compiled in luac is 78 42 bytecode
on Mac OSX Tiger (big endian), 62 when compiled in luac is 40 4F bytecode

Shouldn't this just be 42 78 when compiled on Mac OSX ?

Is there a change I can make to lua src files so that luac will do the above for all integer values? compile them as windows does but with big endian bytecode order? Need to do this for a game I am modding and it is very time consuming manually changing all integer values hex.

Comment: You can use [Lua bytecode viewer and converter](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) to convert bytecode from Little-endian to Big-endian.

Comment: See http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-06/msg00205.html and other posts; search for LoadMem.